# (How) can I make JAXB (MOXy) accept non-getters for marshalling?

Tags: java, interface, marshalling, getter, moxy

JAXB can be efficiently used for dumping structures into XML with just few annotations. The poetry of JAXB is in not really needing to create some DTOs or or clutter the marshalled class too much with boilerplate code.

But it often happens that the method which provides the data is not a getter, rather something like formatDescription() or even toString().

This doesn't matter much if it's just a single class, as it can be subclassed with getDescription() added.
But with when leveraging MOXy's feature to marshall interfaces, this becomes harder - the method would have to be added to the interface and all implementations changed; or the interface subclassed and all impls too.

```
// @XmlElement(name = "desc") // DOESN'T WORK.
String toDescription();

// JAXB needs getter :/
@XmlElement(name = "desc")
String getDescription();
```

Is there any way to make MOXy accept methods not starting with `get*`?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that [MOXy allows external metadata in XML files](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/Mappings/Bidirectional) (instead of annotations). 
Also described in [Jaxb EclipseLink/MOXy : Is it possible to specify the names of get/set methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834871/jaxb-eclipselink-moxy-is-it-possible-to-specify-the-names-of-get-set-methods).

So in this case, I'd set

```
<xml-bindings xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="forum8834871">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="ServerInfo" xml-accessor-type="PUBLIC_MEMBER">
            <xml-root-element/>
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element name="desc" java-attribute="description" >
                    <xml-access-methods get-method="toDescription"/>
                </xml-element>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

Not tested, may not work if I omit the `set-method`.

Anyway - it's just a workaround, so I [filled a feature request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=410120).